# Interactive sorting of grouped bar chart in D3js

Tags: charts, d3.js, interactive

I have generated a group bar chart based on the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/3887051) provided in D3js.org example repository. Now I am trying to introduce an interactive sorting option based on another [example](http://bl.ocks.org/3885705) from D3js example sets. 
I have three variables grouped per state. I was hoping to provide interaction where reader can sort (descending) based on -
1. Any one of the variables (but whole group should move)
3. Three different sorting options one for each variable (complicated and less important)

I am new to javascript and D3js so I am not sure of the way moving forward. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post what you have and what you've tried.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/3n8hjybn/

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I can only offer a very vague direction:

you may need a function that gets called, each time the viewer change sorting option. Inside the function, you will need to specify different accessor:

```
var update = function(_value){
  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b._value - a._value; })

  // add transition with the newly sorted data
}
```